# Firebase database rules: .exists() always true

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to allow people to refer friends within a game. There is a bonus for adding multiple friends and I am trying to avoid exploitation of random user names being added. So I want to check, before they add the user to their list that the user actually exists and that the user signed up with their referal code.

Here is an example of the structure of my database:

```
"friends": {
    "qwerty12345": {
        "friend1": {},
        "friend2": {},
        "friend3": {},
        "friend4": {},
    }
},
"users": {
    "qwerty12345": {},
    "salamander12345": {},
    "harrypotter12345": {}
}
```

so, with the above structure;

When someone signups there is a friend referrer set. This is the **"account uid"** of the friend that referred them. What I want to do is add the current user uid as a child of friends > referring friend.

so, lets say user `pikachu12345` signs up from a link sent from their friend `qwerty12345`. The structure will look like:

```
"friends": {
    "qwerty12345": {
        "pikachu12345": {},
    }
},
```

I only want to add to `friends > qwerty12345 > pikachu12345` **if** that `qwerty12345` exists in `users`.

I have this rule set up:

```
"friends": {
    "$user": {
      ".write": "$user === newData.child('account_uid').val() && root.child('users').child(newData.child('account_uid').val()).exists()"
    }
  },
```

> Edit: newData.child('account_uid').val() = refers to the data object that is being passed (below) and this evaluates as `qwerty12345`

However,when I set the referring friend to `hercule12345` which **does not** exist in the users table. It still adds it to the friends tree.

Why is it always evaluating true?

edit, Also in case it is relevant, this is being written using a Cloud Function:

```
var data = {
        account_uid: "qwerty12345",
        current_user:"pikachu12345"
    }
admin.database().ref(`/friends/${data.account_uid}/${data.current_user}`).set(data)
```

Comment: The `exists` in your rules refer to a child `account_uid`, which I don't see in your JSON anywhere. I get that you've simplified the data structure for the question (thank for that), but please make sure it actually reproduces the problem you have (for example: by reproducing the problem in isolation, and seeing how far you can minimize it).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry, I see my mistake I did not change the value below of the data obj.. I mentioned above that `account_uid` is the friend that referred them. So in this case, it is `qwerty12345`. I have made an edit.

Comment: I just noticed that you're saying the write happens from Cloud Functions. Security rules are not applied to writes from the Admin SDK, unless you set a `databaseAuthVariableOverride`. Did you set that? If you did, can you try reproducing the same problem in the simulator, which typically gives a bit more detail on the exact rule/clause that is rejecting the operation.